# IBOutlets properties. Release or not release

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, properties, iboutlet

I'm developing an iOS 4 application.

I have this ViewController:

```
@interface BlogViewController : UIViewController 
{
    ...

    UIView* tabBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView* tabBar;
```

And its implementation:

And its implementation:

```
@implementation BlogViewController

@synthesize tabBar;

- (void) dealloc
{
    ...

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.tabBar = nil;
}
```

My question if I have a `IBOutlet` property, is it necessary to declare the `UIView` like this?

```
@interface BlogViewController : UIViewController 
{
    ...

    UIView* tabBar;
}
```

If I do it, Do I need to release it on `dealloc`?

```
- (void) dealloc
    {
        ...
        [tabBar release];

        [super dealloc];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order: no you don't need to declare the instance variable, yes you do need to release the object. You may consider using Automatic Reference Counting to get the memory management aspect correct for you.

Comment: Ok. So, if I only use IBOutlet as a property, I don't have to do anything else (only on `- (void)viewDidUnload;`), right? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's because you gave the property `retain` memory attribute. You have to balance the retain of setting its value with a release on dealloc or `viewDidUnload`. With an `assign` property, that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `dealloc` or `viewDidUnload` ? Does that mean if we release it in `viewDidUnload` we don't need to in `dealloc`?

Comment: you should release it in both, setting the instance variable to `nil` after each so that you don't send messages to a stale object pointer. But it really sounds like you'd benefit from Automatic Reference Counting.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to make sure it was AND and not OR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to release an IBOutlet, **if** you retained it.

However, IBOutlets are owned by their nib file, so the usual practice is to use an `assign` or `weak` `@property` instead of `retain` or `strong`. In which case you **don't** need to release it.

Comment: Ok. And, if I use assing, on `viewDidUnload`, may I have to set `self.tabBar = nil;`? Thanks.

Comment: Of course, why not. With `assign` or `weak` property, if you set it to `nil`, it just sets the pointer to `nil` and does nothing else.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both answers have been very useful.

Comment: Outlets aren't "owned by their nib file". They're retained by their superviews. In most cases that unfolds to being the top-level view which is retained by the view controller. Having `retain` properties for outlets is double-counting.

Comment: @GrahamLee Why is it then that if I create an `NSObject` in IB and assign it to an `assign` property, it doesn't get deallocated?

Comment: because it's retained by its superview, which is ultimately retained by the view controller.

Comment: An `NSObject` isn't a view. How can it have a superview? I'm talking about a vanilla `NSObject` (not a subclass), put into the "Objects" section of IB at the top of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xcode 4+ then while creating the outlet it itself makes a release for the same in dealloc and viewDidUnload so no need to do it again.